# ASP.NET Core 3.1 HTML / JavaScript only project - howto configure?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

At the moment I am trying to create a HTML and javascript-only website, that communicates with a REST API. Both projects are in the same solution within Visual Studio as ASP.NET Core 3.1 projects. I figured out to use the `UseStaticFiles` method in the Startup class.

But at the moment I get a 404 error.

Does anyone have a clue about this?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Error]

Ok, I was on the right track, but had a non visible error. Deleting the .vs folder solved the issue.